# How can I include the private key when running AWS jobs with GNU parallel?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2, gnu-parallel

How can one run parallel jobs on Amazon AWS EC2 with gnu parallel? I need to include private key to log in namely something like this does not work:

```
sh script.sh | parallel --sshlogin a@b.com -i "key.pem"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways to do it from GNU Parallel:

```
seq 10 | parallel --sshlogin 'ssh -i "key.pem" a@b.com' echo 

seq 10 | PARALLLEL_SSH='ssh -i "key.pem"' parallel --sshlogin a@b.com echo 

seq 10 | parallel --ssh 'ssh -i "key.pem"' --sshlogin a@b.com echo
```

On top of that you can probably use .ssh/config (man ssh_config), so you use the same key for access to *.amazon.com.

Also you should learn `ssh-agent`. With that you can add multiple keys. Though this is only useful in sessions with a controlling terminal (e.g. not useful for cron jobs).

Comment: Thank you; you are the best!